# Why cannot a primitive of $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ be equal to $-\textrm{arccot} x$?

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

Just giving a thought as to why $\int\frac1{1+x^2}\, dx$ cannot be 
$-\operatorname{arccot} (x)$?

Comment: What makes you think it cannot be?

Comment: its $\, arctan(x)$

Answer (score 3):

It can be. The tables list
$$\int\frac1{1+x^2}\,dx=\arctan x,$$
but $\arctan x+\operatorname{arccot} x=\pi/2$. At least for suitable choices of branches. The primitive is defined only up to an additive constant.

Answer (score 1):

It can...

[image: arccot]

..........................................